# Python Bottle - forms post/get repeating function every refresh

Tags: python, bottle

I have a page with a list of items which includes their id, name, price and stock level. This information is gotten from a SQLite3 database and entered onto the page in a table. The table also has a column where the user can add or remove stock of the item.

This code shows a section of the table:

```
% for i in items:
<tr>
    <th scope="row">{{i[0]}}</th>
    <td>{{i[1]}}</td>
    <td>{{i[2]}}</td>
    <td>{{i[3]}}</td>
    <td><form method="post" action="/worker"><input type="number" name="newStock.{{i[0]}}"><input style="margin-left: 5px" type="submit" Value="Submit"></form></td>
</tr>
% end
```

And here is the Python bottle code for this page

```
@route('/worker', method='GET')
def workerPage1():
    return template('worker', items=store.printItems(2)) # 1 prints out for shoppers, 2 prints out for workers.

@route('/worker', method='POST')
def workerPage2():
    # allows to receive ItemId
    for k in request.forms:
        if k.startswith('newStock.'):
            itemId = k.partition('.')[-1]
            numStock = request.forms.get(k)
            store.updateStock(itemId,numStock) # this accesses the database, updating the stock level

    return template('worker', items=store.printItems(2))
```

The problem I am getting, is that when I enter the stock to be added, say for example '8' it does it fine. But then when I refresh the page, it adds another 8 onto it. So if it was at 22 and then I click submit to add the stock, it would go to 30 and then when I refreshed the page it would go to 38, etc.

Any idea on how to stop this from happening?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `return template('worker', items=store.printItems(2))` in `workerPage2()`, I used `return redirect('worker')`. Works as I wanted.